# my wishlist not align in my toolbar in android

Tags: android

[image: outputimage]

Hi,my wishlist icon is not align in right corner,i want to fix the wishlist heart symbol as corner,as well as need to show full textview header,how to set my toolbar correctly,sorry for my poor english,Here is my xml i am tried this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgback"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/whitearrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="The Complete React Native"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarywhite"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfav"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/whiteheart" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this make `RelativeLayout` as direct child of your `Toolbar` than

- make your **imgback** `ImageView` **==>** `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`
- make your **toolbar_title** `TextView` **==>** `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`
- make your **imgfav** `ImageView` **==>** `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

**sample code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgback"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/whitearrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="The Complete React Native"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarywhite"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgfav"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/whiteheart" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, You Don't need to add any Layouts,
just only add property **gravity**.

add `android:layout_gravity="left"` - Back arrow ImageView
add  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` - TextView
add `android:layout_gravity="right|end"` - wishlist Imageview

& remove `Relative layout` and, it will work fine,

I hope this helps you,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgback"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/whitearrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="The Complete React Native"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarywhite"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgfav"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```